# WCF in a domainless setting

Tags: wcf, web-services, security

I have a .NET client-server system, which uses WCF for communication.

The communication must be secure. Up to now I used Windows Credentials for authentication.

But now a new requirement emerged - the system must work in a situation, when client and server are located in different domains (or the client isn't in any domain).

Windows Credentials authentication won't work in this setting. AFAIR, WCF supports following security mechanisms

- Windows Authentication
- X509 Certificates
- Issued Tokens
- Username and password.

Which of them should I use, if

1. I need to implement the fix with the least possible effort,
2. client and server are located in different domains (therefore, Windows authentication is not an option) and
3. the communication must be secure (the server must not process requests from unauthorized clients)

?

Comment: I'm personally a fan of MLS using certificates.

Comment: @zimdanen Please explain the meaning of the MLS acronym.

Comment: [Message-Level Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733137.aspx)